# Should jumping between words loop in NVDA screen reader?

Tags: accessibility, wcag, nvda

We have a hamburger menu, when it's closed we prevent focus from going inside it. When it's opened we allow focus only inside the menu using "inert" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert

Our designer says that pressing Control + Right arrow, to jump between words on a website using NVDA, should loop; e.g. when you reach the end of the page it should start over from the first word in the menu. Is this true? If it's true why doesn't it work? I tried a simple index.html page with only html and it does not loop.

Can anyone provide proof to disproove this claim?

Comment: I’m a bit puzzled about your statements concerning focus. When closed, the entire menu should not be accessible at all, neither for focus, nor for reading. Is that the case? `inert` does not (only) allow focus within, but forbids focus outside.

Comment: The explanation of how loop should work seems incoherent as well. Reading the menu should only be possible when it’s open. So when reaching the end of the page (outside the menu), and the read cursor wraps, it must not start inside the menu.

Comment: How a screen reader should behave, is not part of the accessibility standards. Whether the read next command wraps to the beginning of the page is up to the screen reader vendor, if it doesn’t work with standard HTML, it’s not the case.